# VB .Net querying a SQL Server DB for average and getting "DS System.Data.DataSet"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

PROBLEM:
When I click (*) Full Time

I get "DS System.Data.DataSet" from the MsgBox.

GOAL:
To get the Average Salary onto the form in the lblAvgSalary.Text label.

```
FORM:
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|Select Employment Status                               |
| +--------------------------------------+  lblAvgSalary|
| | ( ) Full Time                        | +---------+  |
| | ( ) Part Time                        | |         |  |
| +--------------------------------------+ +---------+  |
|                                                       |
| +--------------------------------------------------+  |
| | DataGridView (Name:DGVData)                      |  |
| |                                                  |  |
| |                                                  |  |
| |                                                  |  |
| +--------------------------------------------------+  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
</BLOCKQUOTE></CODE>
```

```
    SQLControl Class:--------------------------------------------------------
    '  Add the System components for SQL (SQL server and SQL Client)
    Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

''' <Remarks>
'''  Connect to the SQL server with a Connection String.  Requires a Pointer, a Database, and Credentials
''' </Remarks>
Public Class SQLControl
    Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=Company;User=sa;Pwd=Password1;"}
    Public SQLCmd As SqlCommand
    Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public SQLDataset As DataSet

    ''' <Remarks>
    '''  Function to check the SQL connection
    ''' </Remarks>
    Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCon.Close()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    ''' <Remarks>
    '''  Run a query and return if it ran successfully
    ''' </Remarks>

    Public Function RunQuery(ByVal Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()

            SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            SQLDataset = New DataSet
            SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

            SQLCon.Close()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                SQLCon.Close()
            End If
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class


MainForm:-----------------------------------------------------------
Public Class MainForm
    Dim SQL As New SQLControl
    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            'MsgBox("Successfully connected!")
            SQL.RunQuery("SELECT Last_name, First_name, Full_Time, Salary FROM SalesStaff")
            If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                DGVData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
            End If

        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub radFullTime_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles radFullTime.CheckedChanged
        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            'MsgBox("FT: Successfully connected!")
            'DGVData.SelectAll()
            'DGVData.ClearSelection()
            SQL.RunQuery("SELECT Last_name, First_name, Full_Time, Salary FROM SalesStaff Where Full_Time = 1")
            If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                DGVData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
            End If
            SQL.RunQuery("Select AVG(Salary) As SalaryAverage From SalesStaff Where Full_Time = 1")
            MsgBox(" DS " & SQL.SQLDataset.ToString)
            'lblAvgSalary.Text = 
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub radPartTime_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles radPartTime.CheckedChanged

        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            '  MsgBox("PT: Successfully connected!")
            'DGVData.SelectAll()
            'DGVData.ClearSelection()
            SQL.RunQuery("SELECT Last_name, First_name, Full_Time, Salary FROM SalesStaff Where Full_Time <> 1")
            If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                DGVData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
            End If

            lblAvgSalary.Text = SQL.RunQuery("Select AVG(Salary) As SalaryAverage From SalesStaff Where Full_Time <> 1")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class

</PRE>

Comment: Use `Option Strict On` always.  The value you want will be a value/field in a row in a table in the Dataset - not the entire dataset (`SQL.SQLDataset.ToString`)

Comment: I'm just trying to get the one piece of data (Average) into one single field if someone could show some code to do that.

Comment: If all you want is one value then don't use a `DataSet` at all.  Create a command object and call its `ExecuteScalar` method.  That will return the value from the first column of the first row of the result set of the query.

Comment: Thanks guys... I don't think I'm being clear... :(  so if I have a dataset with 10 people with 10 different salaries.  I need to get the average of all those salaries into one string so I can plug that into my form.

Thanks Plutonix, I did add <code>Option Strict On</code> to my code.